# Can't access any of Linq methods

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a simple ApiController for getting product stocks, but I'm having a strange issue. I get the data from a method that returns a `System.Linq.IQueryable` (In a library), but I can't apply any of the Linq methods, like `Count` or `ToList()`. The import directive is present and doesn't report any problem. Also intellisense shows `Data` as `System.Linq.IQueryable`.

The code:

```
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Linq

Public Class ProductSearchController
    Inherits ApiController

    Public Function Get(...) As IQueryable

        Dim nvc As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query)
        Dim sEcho As String = nvc("sEcho").ToString()
        Dim iDisplayStart As Integer = CType(nvc("iDisplayStart"), Integer)

        'Signature of Stock:  public IQueryable Stock(...)
        Dim Data = New GenericSearches().Stock(...)
        Dim Count As Integer = Data.Count() 'Error Here!

        Dim result = New DataTableResult With {
            .sEcho = sEcho,
            .iTotalRecords = Count,
            .iTotalDisplayRecords = Count,
            .aaData = Data.ToList() 'Error Here!
            }
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Also, I noticed that error correction and intellisense asks me to choose those methods from a weird Devexpress library something like DevXpress.Data.Helpers.Linq.

Comment: What *exactly* is the error? If you hover over `Data`, what does it show the type as?

Comment: @JonSkeet : The queston says it is `System.Linq.IQueryable`

Comment: Oh, and also: if you type `Data.` what members *does* Intellisense suggest?

Comment: @Sandesh: Had missed the Intellisense part... oops!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-generic [`IQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable) interface *doesn't* have extension methods of `Count` and `ToList()`. Only the generic [`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562) does.

If you can modify the library to return a suitable `IQueryable<T>`, I suggest you do so. If you can't, you may need to call `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>()` to create an appropriate `IQueryable<T>` with the right extension methods.

Comment: You mean like IQueryable<DataRow> or IQueryable<Object> ?
The data comes initially from a dataTable.

Comment: @Sergio: Yes, exactly. Although if it's coming from a `DataTable`, why are you using `IQueryable<T>` at all (rather than `IEnumerable<T>`)?

Comment: I'm currently using an old DAL that still can't deal with paged queries. So I have a service that gets the data and then the paging it's managed between this and the apicontroller. Also I don't remember if it was a requirement for a REST web api and AttributeRouting. Does it make sense?
Anyway, your solution runs smooth like silk. Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio: It doesn't make a lot of sense, to be honest - if the paging is all done locally, you could still just use `IEnumerable<T>`. I think it would be worth revisiting your approach - but I'm glad that the workaround helped for the moment.